# Pass array to jQuery each function to reformat data

Tags: jquery, json, parsing, scope

I've got a data set of Json data which needs to be reformatted.

The data is structured like this in rows as part of 1 Object:

```
"2019-12-27": Object{'a':'1', 'b':'2', 'c':'3', 'd':'4'}
```

I want to parse each row so that it's like this (or an array) and combine all the rows into 1 object:

```
["2019-12-27", "1", "2", "3", "4"]
```

This is the code I tried using $.each functions, which mostly works, but fails because the array is from outside the scope of the inner function. - `TypeError: parsed[count] is undefined` Is there a way to pass the parsed array from the outer to the inner loop?

```
parsed = [];
var count = 0;
$.each(data, function(k, outer) {
  count += 1;
  parsed[count][] = k;
  $.each(outer, function(i, inner) {
    parsed[count][] = i;
    });
});
```

Comment: It's easier to understand data when it uses appropriate syntax. It looks like you're copying and pasting from the console. If that's the case, use `console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2))` and copy/paste the output of that into your question.

Comment: Also, JSON is a text format; what you have there is part of an object.

Comment: I meant it to be an array or list. I'll edit it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need jQuery for this. [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) and the [`...` spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) will do the job quite well:

```js
const input = {
   "2019-12-27": {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4}
  ,"2019-12-28": {'a':2, 'b':4, 'c':6, 'd':8}
};
const output = Object.entries(input)
                     .map(entry => [entry[0], ...Object.values(entry[1])]);

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Why the DV? Just curios if I did miss something which should be improved or removed?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot push to an array using short-handed C syntax `(list[] = val)`. You would be looking for an array method called `push`

```
var x = []; // declare an array
var myObject = { a: 1, b: 2 }; // Defining an example object
var mySecondObject = { a: 3, b: 5 }; // another sample object
x.push(myObject);
x.push(mySecondObject);

console.log(x);
```

Output:

```
[
    { a: 1, b: 2 },
    { a: 3, b: 5 }
]
```

If we were to use the code you provided:

```
var parsed = [];
var count = 0;
$.each(data, function(k, outer) {
  count += 1;
  parsed[count].push(k);
  $.each(outer, function(i, inner) {
    parsed[count].push(i);
    });
});
```

You don't necessarily need the count variable if you want to allow push to determine auto 0 based indexes.

Comment: still getting `TypeError: parsed[count] is undefined`

Comment: I edited the answer. We forgot to declare `parsed` with the `var` keyword. My bad.